# How do I deal with Firebase init?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

**hosting problem**

Firebase init choosing hosting:configure files for Firebase....
I got this problem:

> Error: Must select at least one feature. Use SPACEBAR to select features, or specify a feature by running `firebase init [feature_name]`
>
> Having trouble? Try `firebase [command] --help`

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explaining, you have to use spacebar to select any of the option available.I think you must have gotten confused with Enter option. you  have to use spacebar for selecting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the option using Spacebar as shown in Picture

[image]